# Creating Report From Datatable When Columns/Rows Varies

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, reportviewer

I've done lots of searching, and can't find anything that helps get me started with this question, so will try and explain my requirements.

I'm in the process of re-writing a legacy VB6 application into C# (Windows Forms), giving us the opportunity to remove unused aspects and also add in some new features.

The legacy application had the ability to print the output, but used FORTRAN modules to achieve this - we don't want to use this old technology, so am looking for a way to take the datasource of a DataGridView (which can be converted to a Datatable with ease) and print it in a structured format.

The only issue that is causing me problems finding examples on how to develop this is that the number of columns can vary from 1 to 10 (or more if they decide to increase this), and the headings are unique as they display actuarial factor tables.

So for example, the first row will be a table name, then any number of rows (from 40 to 95).

Had the data been in a structure where the column headings are fixed, there are lots of examples, but none that I can find that deal with dynamic columns.

The application development is already in progress, so I was looking to use the ReportViewer built into VS (2012), but could not find any examples for dynamic columns. I need to at least replicate the output from the legacy version (can provide examples if necessary), and if not improve on it.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1212707/2632838.aspx#2632838)? And if you are modernizing a legacy app why are you using VS2012 and WinForms?

Comment: While I realise it is not one of the most modern ways to go about it, one of the easiest plug-ins to use and quite flexible is Crystal Reports you could have a look at that. @Crowcoder Winforms are still a prefered choice when making lightweight data management applications or requiring specific libraries not available to WPF

Comment: @Kostas Balis, I have more experience than I care to with Crystal reports and I've never heard anyone call it easy. Anyway, OP is using rdlc (or possibly rdl, its not quite clear).

Comment: @Crowcoder - thanks, i had, but Initially dismissed it as I'm not getting my data from SQL - the data is from flat text files, loaded into a DataGridView.    And the reason we have stayed with C# WinForms is to ensure there is familiarity to allow it be supported across the developers in my team. Out of interest - what would you suggest was used?

Comment: @Kostas Balis - I had considered Crystal Reports, but as am already into development, and don't have it installed, was not clear to me if I would have to re-work the project?

Comment: @MartinS, I would think new development be using the Universal Windows Platform, but if that is not appropriate for your user base then at least WPF. Not that winforms is bad, it is just a less common choice these days.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder. i've had a quick look at UWP but appears to be Win10 - am still running Win7, so will look in more detail at WPF. Would using WPF make my issue any easier to answer?

Comment: @MartinS, well no, I just mention it because it is unusual to revamp legacy systems with (what many many would say) is a legacy system. But there are more powerful reporting tools if you have a budget foe it.

Comment: Fair comment. We mainly build in C#/MVC for web, but this is an internal only tool that has always been forms based, so it seemed sensible to stick to WinForms. I'll discuss this further with management and maybe look to migrate this over to at least a WPF project. Thanks.

Comment: WinForms works fine for millions of users and thousands of companies.  Just because it is old doesn't mean you can't use it.  It is still supported and still widely used.  I'm not hear to argue that though.  If you want to dynamically create columns in a `DataGridView` it is actually quite easy.  I use that control all the time and don't touch the WinForms designer.  I'll post a simple example of how to dynamically create columns below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick example of how to dynamically create columns and place them into a `DataGridView`.

```
var dgv = new DataGridView();

var dgvTextColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dgvTextColumn.Name = "columnName"; // to use for future column references
dgvTextColumn.DataPropertyName = "columnName"; // I prefer to keep this and .Name property the same
dgvTextColumn.HeaderText = "columnHeader";
dgvTextColumn.Width = 50;
dgvTextColumn.ReadOnly = false;
dgv.Columns.Add(dgvTextColumn);
```

This is a really simple example.  I personally store the columns I want to create in a database table along with some basic column properties such as width, readonly, etc.  Loop through all the columns and create them iterating over the code above.  This way I can update the columns I want to display without recompiling the application.  I also break out those stored columns with a case statement based on what type of column to create so that I can do combo, text, button and checkbox columns.

Most importantly you have to make sure when you dynamically create columns that your `DataSourceName` exists in the data source you set for the `DataGridView`.

If you want a more complex answer, let me know.

Comment: Thanks @jaredbaszler. Populating the datagridview is not my issue though - it's being able to take the source and print it that I'm struggling with. I looked at the ReportViewer, and the examples I found 'seemed' to require a structure for the columns, and as my content can be any number of columns, each with a unique heading, it did not seem to fit. So ultimately what I'm after is suggestions on other methods of printing from the source of a DGV.

Comment: @MartinS - for this functionality we use Telerik's awesome control suite.  Their Winforms RadGridView has many exporting options.  You can read more [here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/gridview/exporting-data/overview).  We are similar to you in that we develop C#/MVC for web apps and in-house we use WinForms.  Telerik DevCraft covers both of these and while the suite is a bit spendy, our subscription has paid for itself many times over already with saved development time.

Comment: Thanks for the link @jaredbaszler. I'll pass the info on. I'm working on sticking with the Reportviewer for the moment - I've got it (kind of) working, except it's not showing the data! I'll post a new question. Thanks again.